# CyVis 0.9 Ant task failing to generate html report

Tags: xml, ant, cyclomatic-complexity

I am currently attempting to make an Ant build file for a Java project that uses CyVis 0.9 as one of its tools. I am running into a problem where I cannot get it to generate an html report. Below is the exact code from my build.xml file, which is almost exactly taken from the tutorial on CyVis' website. Currently, it is generating a text report just fine; however, the text reports are less than helpful.

I have run this same exact code on a team member's computer and it has worked perfectly fine. Since then I have reinstalled CyVis and Ant and have had no luck.

```
<path id="cyvis.path">
   <fileset dir="${cyvis.home.dir}">
       <include name="**/*.jar"/>
   </fileset> 
</path>
<taskdef name="cyvis" 
    classname="cyvis.ant.CyvisTask" 
    classpathref="cyvis.path"
/>
<target name="report.cyvis">
    <mkdir dir="${report.cyvis.dir}" />
    <cyvis verbose="false" home="${cyvis.home.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${bin.dir}">
            <include name="**\*.class"/>
        </fileset>
        <report type="text"  outFile="${report.cyvis.dir}\test.txt" />
        <report type="html"  outFile="${report.cyvis.dir}\index.html" />
    </cyvis>
</target>
```

Upon running the build I get the following output:

```
report.cyvis:
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Dustin\workspace\H2\report\cyvis
[cyvis] Text report generated, see C:\Users\Dustin\workspace\H2\report\cyvis\test.txt

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Dustin\workspace\H2\build.xml:319: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException: Invalid final field cyvis.metric.ProjectMetric.classes
```

When commenting the html report out, the build is successful, but only produces the text report. I have had no luck researching this error and cannot see any differences between mine and my colleague's set up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java XStream Deep Copy raises Exception ObjectAccessException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466032/java-xstream-deep-copy-raises-exception-objectaccessexception)